# Deprecated property caller in browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

Experimenting with the deprecated `"caller"` property, I came across unusual behavior in browsers. The following browsers were used: `Google Chrome 79.0.3945.117`, `Firefox 72.0.1`, `Edge 44.18362.449.0`

Let's start with a basic example:

```
function start(){}
start.hasOwnProperty("caller")
```

Google Chrome: `true`, Firefox: `false`, Edge: `true`

Well, the truth is that only in Firefox does not use its own "caller" property for each declared function.

In such example:

```
function start(){"use strict"};
start.hasOwnProperty("caller")
```

Google Chrome: `false`, Firefox: `false`, Edge: `false`

---

Let's look at the following code

```
function a(){b()}
function b(){"use strict";c()}
function c(){console.log(c.caller)}
delete Function.prototype.caller;
a()
```

And what do we see? We see that only an error occurs in Edge, and Google Chrome hides it by showing us the value null, Firefox returns undefined because it cannot find such a property with the name `"caller"` anywhere.

Although this case is described by the specification as:

> If an implementation extends any function object with an own property named "caller" the value of that property, as observed using [[Get]] or [[GetOwnProperty]], must not be a strict function object. If it is an accessor property, the function that is the value of the property's [[Get]] attribute must never return a strict function when called.

If we execute the code above but remove `"use strict"` then in Google Chrome and Edge we will notice that the entry `console.log (c.caller)` gives us a function that called the current function and this if there is no `"caller"` property in `Function.prototype`. But Firefox in this situation is silent and produces the same result as in strict mode - `"undefined"`.

By the way, if we remove the prototypes of these functions, nothing will change:

```
function a(){b()}
function b(){"use strict";c()}
function c(){console.log(c.caller)}
delete Function.prototype.caller;
Object.setPrototypeOf(a,null);
Object.setPrototypeOf(b,null);
Object.setPrototypeOf(c,null);
a();
```

With Firefox, everything is extremely simple:

1. In strict mode

   1. The `"caller"` property is not defined for the function
   2. When calling the `"caller"` property, the property is taken from `Function.prototype`
   3. Calling the `"caller"` property throws an error.
2. In normal mode

   1. The `"caller"` property is not defined for the function
   2. When calling the `"caller"` property, the property is taken from `Function.prototype`
   3. Calling the `"caller"` property does not throw an error.

Although Firefox is not so simple either. The specification says the following: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addrestrictedfunctionproperties. That is, the specification says that you need to define properties with errors in `Function.prototype` when they are called. The specification clearly defines the `"caller"` accessor property as a property that contains an error. But Firefox in normal mode, the "caller" property seems to be either overridden or initially initially defined on two types of code: strict and not strict. Is this behavior a Firefox implementation error?

Regarding Google Chrome and Edge:

1. In strict mode

   1. The `"caller"` property is not defined for the function
   2. When calling the `"caller"` property, the property is taken from `Function.prototype`
   3. Calling the "caller" property throws an error.
2. In normal mode

   1. The `"caller"` property is defined for the function
   2. When the `"caller"` property is called, the property is not taken from `Function.prototype` (where?)
   3. Calling the `"caller"` property does not throw an error.

The most incomprehensible thing in this situation is how Google Chrome and Edge get a value for the `"caller"` property with the removed `Function.prototype` (in `Function.prototype` there is a getter and setter of the `"caller"` property, and in a regular function, the `"caller"` property has neither getter nor setter)?

Comment: Function.prototype.caller is not properly specified yet, see this long discussion: https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/562.

Comment: @evilpie I know what Function.prototype.caller is not specified. If you read my post carefully, you would understand that my questions are about browser behavior and not specification. In addition, the specification has a number of limitations regarding the "caller" property. And it looks like Firefox breaks them when in normal code it creates not an accessor property with an error in Function.Prototype.caller but an accessory property with a function that shows the function that called the current code.

Answer (score -1):

The [function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) property returns the function that invoked the specified function. This property is **forbidden** in **strict mode**.